# Skipio API Add New Contacts to Groups

Tags: php, api

I'm currently using the Skipio API (Homepage: https://skipio.com/) (API: http://docs.skipio.apiary.io/#).

I was able to get the 'Create a New Contact' to work but I was wondering if anyone else has found out how to add the new user to a pre-existing group?